# save image to blob in webkit and gecko

Tags: javascript, webkit, xmlhttprequest, blob, gecko

I need to download image file by ajax, save it to blob and later display in image tag. In webkit I am using

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
var imgSrc = "test.jpg";
xhr.responseType = 'arraybuffer';
xhr.open("GET", imgSrc, true);
xhr.onload = function (oEvent) {
  console.log('onload1');
  var blob = new Blob([xhr.response], {type: "image/jpg"});
  console.log(blob.size);
  var img = document.createElement('img');
  img.onload = function() {
    console.log('onload2');
    document.body.appendChild(img);
  }
  img.onerror = function() {
    console.log('error');
  }
  img.src = webkitURL.createObjectURL(blob);
}
xhr.send(null);
```

The image size is 43312 and blob size is 43312. The image is displayed correctly, so far so good. Now let's move to gecko:

First, I get stucked on xhr.responseType = 'arraybuffer'; For some reason, firefox accepts only 'arrayBuffer' and not 'arraybuffer'. That's quite confusing because according to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2FXMLHttpRequest, gecko should accept arraybuffer as well.

Then I replace webkitURL with URL. Image is downloaded, blob is created, but with size 77978 and image loding failed (obviously, image data are broken).

Comment: Why don't you `xhr.responseType = 'blob';` and skip a step.

Comment: Ok, mystery solved.

In firefox, you need to do xhr.open first and then you can set responseType to arraybuffer.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, mystery solved.

In firefox, you need to do xhr.open first and then you can set responseType to arraybuffer.